# Flutter app does not contain podhelper.rb file in its ios/Flutter folder

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, integration

I am trying to link Flutter app to my existing iOS app. I'm following [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup) and trying integration  with cocoapods as mentioned in the document. Problem is that pod is not able to find the podhelper.rb file. I checked the project structure, the file is not there by default.

I created the project using latest Android Studio Chipmunk. Here is the default structure of the flutter app. [Flutter app's ios folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55hKO.png)

As per the link, for integration to work, this link should be added,

```
load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')
```

Since file is not there, I am not able to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try flutter clean, cd ios and pod install from your flutter project's root directory? Then try flutter run or flutter build ios

Comment: could you solve it?

Comment: I am facing this issue in my Azure Pipeline -> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- airshipfluttersdk/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb.
In local machine it was working fine. Did anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your podfile

```
flutter_application_path ='path/to/my_flutter/'
  eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path,'.ios','Flutter','podhelper.rb')), binding)
```

Also make sure you are in master channel

Comment: Hi Kaushik, I tried what you suggested, same result.
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../test_project_camera/ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb.
Problem is, ios/Flutter folder doesn't even have podhelper.rb file. You can check the Flutter folder structure I have shared.

Comment: Seems like your Podfile isn't being recognised.. Can you share your Podfile in the question please

Comment: Hi @KaushikChandru I am facing this issue in my Azure Pipeline -> [!] Invalid Podfile file: cannot load such file -- airshipfluttersdk/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb. In local machine it was working fine. Can you help me what is the issue exactly? I am in master channel

Comment: Whats the path that you gave in flutter path?

Comment: @KaushikChandru                                                                               flutter_application_path = '../my_flutter_app'
load File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb') I am using stable channel